# Create instance from web.config and with dependency injection in constructor with Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create an instance of an object from a web.config configuration, like this:

```
<add name="Log4Net" type="Spm.Services.Logging.Log4NetServices.Log4NetReporting, Spm.Services" />
```

The type `Log4NetReporting` has a constructor with an argument I want to inject, like this:

```
public class NLogReporting : ILogReporting
{
    [Inject]
    public NLogReporting(IRepository<NLogError> nLogRepository)
    {
        this.nLogRepository = nLogRepository;
    }
}
```

I was trying to create an instance of this object by doing this:

```
var logger = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ILogReporting;
```

But I get an exception saying "No parameterless constructor has been define for this object".

Ideally, I would like to do this using Ninject but I don't know how. My code is separated in different assemblies so the Ninject initialization (look below) is in one assembly (the Web application assembly) and this code is in the Services assembly.

Here's my Ninject initialization code:

```
private static StandardKernel CreateNinjectKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    RegisterNinjectServices(kernel);
    ConfigureAutoMapper(kernel);
    return kernel;
}

private static void RegisterNinjectServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<NLogError>>().To<Repository<EntityDbContext, NLogError>>().InRequestScope();
}
```

Is this possible to do or am I just doing it all wrong?

/Ingo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ideally you would have `ILogReporting` injected into the service that would use it.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly ILogReporting _logger;

    public SomeService(ILogReporting logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // .... code....
}
```

but if you need to request the instance at the time of execution, not creation, then you will need some way to access the DI container (the Ninject Kernel) from wherever you are trying to get the `ILogReporting` instance. Ninject's WebAPI integration wires its Kernel up to the `System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver`, so we can use that.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly IDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public SomeService(IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        _resolver = resolver;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        var logger = _resolver.GetService<ILogReporting>();
        // .... code....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave! That helped a lot!